# Special effects in XNA 3D?

Tags: c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

How can I create effects such as smoke, fire, and explosions, in my game using XNA 4.0? If it uses the Reach Profile, that is ok because my graphics card is very bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You propably want to look into [Billboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Move_to_3D) and [Particles](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2010/10/08/2d-particles-in-xna-part-1-of-3/). Combined you can create Smoketrails, rain, explosions, fireworks and what not.

Comment: I want to create effect in XNA game 3D, not 2D

Comment: I know, thats why i gave you the link to Billboards, billboards are for 3D. You will also find in the XNA tutorials one about billboards, should be a good place to start aswell.